OpenGL no lights, black window
I'm trying to do an assignment:


Texturing: The letter "M" is textured to resemble it being sculpted from marble.
Marbling: Adjust the textures to make it appear as if the entire object was sculpted from a single block. Pay close attention to the edges of the shape.
Shading: Implement the Phong lighting model correctly where most calculations occur in the fragment shader. Adjust the alpha coefficient to blend well with the marble surface.
Lighting Color: While the material color should be derived from the texture, the lighting color should be a proper shade of blue.
Variable Lighting Color: Set up the light source so that its color cycles smoothly between three primary shades of blue (#141e50, #006cfa, #23bdff). The transition should be seamless over time.


...and I don't know why it shows me a black window below, I send the Program, fragment_shader and vertex_shader, when I change the background color to, for example, gray, my object is shown as black, as if light did not exist, these are my tasks that I have to do, obj rendered correctly:
using GLFW;
using GlmSharp;
using ObjLoader;
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4;
using Shaders;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace PMLabs
{
    public class BC : IBindingsContext
    {
        public IntPtr GetProcAddress(string procName)
        {
            return Glfw.GetProcAddress(procName);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static ShaderProgram shader;
        static float speed_y;
        static float speed_x;
        static int tex;
        static KeyCallback kc = KeyProcessor;

        static int vertexArray;
        static int vertexBuffer;
        static int indexBuffer;
        static int indexCount;

      
        static vec3 lightColor = new vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); 
        static vec3 lightPos = new vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);   
        static vec3 viewPos = new vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f);    
        static float shininess = 32.0f;                      

        public static void KeyProcessor(IntPtr window, Keys key, int scanCode, InputState state, ModifierKeys mods)
        {
            if (state == InputState.Press)
            {
                if (key == Keys.Left) speed_y = -3.14f;
                if (key == Keys.Right) speed_y = 3.14f;
                if (key == Keys.Up) speed_x = -3.14f;
                if (key == Keys.Down) speed_x = 3.14f;
            }
            if (state == InputState.Release)
            {
                if (key == Keys.Left || key == Keys.Right) speed_y = 0;
                if (key == Keys.Up || key == Keys.Down) speed_x = 0;
            }
        }

        public static void InitOpenGLProgram(Window window)
        {
            GL.ClearColor(Color.Black);

            shader = new ShaderProgram("vertex_shader.glsl", "fragment_shader.glsl");
            Glfw.SetKeyCallback(window, kc);
            GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
            tex = ReadTexture("marble.jpg");

            try
            {
                var objParser = new ObjParser("triangle.obj");

                vertexArray = GL.GenVertexArray();
                GL.BindVertexArray(vertexArray);

                vertexBuffer = GL.GenBuffer();
                GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vertexBuffer);
                GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, objParser.Vertices.Count * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(vec3)), objParser.Vertices.ToArray(), BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

                var positionLocation = shader.A("aPosition");
                GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
                GL.VertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(vec3)), 0);

                // Dodaj obsługę normalnych wierzchołków
                var normalLocation = shader.A("aNormal");
                GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(normalLocation);
                GL.VertexAttribPointer(normalLocation, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(vec3)), objParser.Vertices.Count * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(vec3)));

                indexBuffer = GL.GenBuffer();
                GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, indexBuffer);
                GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, objParser.Indices.Count * sizeof(int), objParser.Indices.ToArray(), BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

                indexCount = objParser.Indices.Count;

                var texCoordLocation = shader.A("aTexCoord");
                GL.VertexAttribPointer(texCoordLocation, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(vec2)), 0);
                GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(texCoordLocation);

                GL.BindVertexArray(0);
            }
            catch (SystemException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error initializing OpenGL program: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        public static void FreeOpenGLProgram(Window window)
        {
            GL.DeleteVertexArray(vertexArray);
            GL.DeleteBuffer(vertexBuffer);
            GL.DeleteBuffer(indexBuffer);
            GL.DeleteTexture(tex);
        }

        public static int ReadTexture(string filename)
        {
            var tex = GL.GenTexture();
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, tex);

            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(filename);
            bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);

            System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData data = bitmap.LockBits(
                new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
                System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, data.Width, data.Height, 0,
                OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4.PixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.UnsignedByte, data.Scan0);

            bitmap.UnlockBits(data);
            bitmap.Dispose();

            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Linear);
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Linear);
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, (int)TextureWrapMode.Repeat);
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, (int)TextureWrapMode.Repeat);

            return tex;
        }

        public static void DrawScene(Window window, float angle_x, float angle_y)
        {
            GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

            mat4 P = mat4.Perspective(glm.Radians(60.0f), 1, 0.1f, 100.0f);
            mat4 V = mat4.LookAt(new vec3(0, 0, -5), new vec3(0, 0, 0), new vec3(0, 1, 0));

            shader.Use();
            GL.UniformMatrix4(shader.U("P"), 1, false, P.Values1D);
            GL.UniformMatrix4(shader.U("V"), 1, false, V.Values1D);

            mat4 M = mat4.Identity;
            M = mat4.Rotate(angle_y, new vec3(0, 1, 0)) * mat4.Rotate(angle_x, new vec3(1, 0, 0));
            M *= mat4.Scale(0.5f);

            GL.UniformMatrix4(shader.U("M"), 1, false, M.Values1D);

            GL.Uniform3(shader.U("light.position"), lightPos.x, lightPos.y, lightPos.z);
            GL.Uniform3(shader.U("viewPos"), viewPos.x, viewPos.y, viewPos.z);
            GL.Uniform3(shader.U("light.color"), lightColor.x, lightColor.y, lightColor.z);
            GL.Uniform1(shader.U("material.shininess"), shininess);

            GL.ActiveTexture(TextureUnit.Texture0);
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, tex);
            GL.Uniform1(shader.U("tex"), 0);

            GL.BindVertexArray(vertexArray);
            GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.Triangles, indexCount, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);

            Glfw.SwapBuffers(window);
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Glfw.Init();

            Window window = Glfw.CreateWindow(500, 500, "OpenGL", GLFW.Monitor.None, Window.None);

            Glfw.MakeContextCurrent(window);
            Glfw.SwapInterval(1);

            GL.LoadBindings(new BC());

            InitOpenGLProgram(window);

            Glfw.Time = 0;
            float angle_x = 0;
            float angle_y = 0;

            while (!Glfw.WindowShouldClose(window))
            {
                angle_x += speed_x * (float)Glfw.Time;
                angle_y += speed_y * (float)Glfw.Time; 
                Glfw.Time = 0; 
                DrawScene(window, angle_x, angle_y);
                Glfw.PollEvents();
            }


            FreeOpenGLProgram(window);

            Glfw.Terminate();
        }
    }
}

#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 aPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 aNormal; 
layout(location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec3 FragPos;
out vec3 Normal;   
out vec2 TexCoord;

uniform mat4 P;
uniform mat4 V;
uniform mat4 M;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = P * V * M * vec4(aPosition, 1.0);
    FragPos = vec3(M * vec4(aPosition, 1.0));
    Normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(M))) * aNormal; 
    TexCoord = aTexCoord;
}

#version 330 core

in vec3 FragPos;
in vec3 Normal;
in vec2 TexCoord;

out vec4 FragColor;

struct Material {
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
    float shininess;
};

struct Light {
    vec3 position;
    vec3 color;
};

uniform vec3 viewPos;
uniform Light light;
uniform Material material;
uniform sampler2D tex;

void main()
{
    vec3 ambient = material.ambient * texture(tex, TexCoord).rgb;

    vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(light.position - FragPos);
    float diff = max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = material.diffuse * diff * light.color * texture(tex, TexCoord).rgb;

    vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - FragPos);
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, norm);
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), material.shininess);
    vec3 specular = material.specular * spec * light.color;

    vec3 result = ambient + diffuse + specular;
    FragColor = vec4(result, 1.0);
}

I've tried everything, I've debugged whether it sends it to the shaders correctly and I can't come up with anything

Start by testing your shader step-by-step. Does it show the texture when you use FragColor = vec4(texture(tex, TexCoord), 1.0); Do the normals look ok when outputting FragColor = vec4(abs(norm),1.0); and so on.
